# Insert the data into the last column

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-sheets

I use python and Google sheet API to insert the data URI from a html, but I dont know how to let the data save in the last column,not the first column.

I use  python3, flask, pandas, Google Sheet API v4.

Is anyone know where should I change or insert function in my code?

```html
import flask
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
from flask_cors import CORS
import pandas as pd
from main import GoogleAPIClient


app = flask.Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True


class GoogleSheets(GoogleAPIClient):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # 呼叫 GoogleAPIClient.__init__()，並提供 serviceName, version, scope
        super().__init__(
            'sheets',
            'v4',
            ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'],
        )

    def appendWorksheet(self, spreadsheetId: str, range: str, df: pd.DataFrame):
        self.googleAPIService.spreadsheets().values().append(
            spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId,
            range=range,
            valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED',
            body={
                'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
                'values': df.values.tolist()
            },
        ).execute()
        return 0

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return "<h1>Hello Flask!</h1>"

@app.route('/test2', methods=['POST'])
def test2():

    data = request.get_json()
    new_data = {
        
        'uri': data['uri']
    }
    myWorksheet = GoogleSheets()
    print(myWorksheet.appendWorksheet(
        spreadsheetId='1R4X_sDKko8QvVLP341DyFC0o0BM8hWiGoKi5JkNu4uA',
        range='工作表1',
        df=pd.DataFrame(
            {
                '體重': [new_data['uri']]
            }
        )
    ))
    return "<h1>Append successful!</h1>"


app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Google Sheets API documentation, the function append will append to the next row:

[image]
[Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append?hl=en&authuser=1&apix_params=%7B%22spreadsheetId%22%3A%221fcU3Ccb3Mcqgl6_cfOP51SxN2zRo9rmagWOR739JR9U%22%2C%22range%22%3A%22A1%22%2C%22includeValuesInResponse%22%3Atrue%2C%22valueInputOption%22%3A%22USER_ENTERED%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%7D%7D)

**Suggestion:**

Here's what you can do instead. You need to get the length of the target row using `spreadsheet.values().get()`
You will then use length from the get on the range you specified so it will be referencing to the last column.

**Example Formula:**

```
    #GET
    result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])

    if not values:
        print('No data found.')
        return
    
    column_len = len(values[0])
    
    #UPDATE
    response = sheet.values().update(
        spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
        range= f"Sheet1!{chr(65+column_len)}1",
        valueInputOption="RAW",
        body= {'values' : [['Inserted test']]},
        ).execute()
```

**From:**
[image]

**Result:**
[image]

References:

- [Append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append?hl=en&authuser=1&apix_params=%7B%22spreadsheetId%22%3A%221fcU3Ccb3Mcqgl6_cfOP51SxN2zRo9rmagWOR739JR9U%22%2C%22range%22%3A%22A1%22%2C%22includeValuesInResponse%22%3Atrue%2C%22valueInputOption%22%3A%22USER_ENTERED%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%7D%7D)
- [Update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: I have an error code the `AttributeError: 'GoogleSheets' object has no attribute 'values'` with using your code in my code . Do you know  where I make mistake?